# What is the best way to call a method in a controller from a service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've done some research on this question both in SO and on Google as well. But none of the answers serve my purpose.

I have a modal in an HTML view, which I use to show popup notifications in my app.
I want to show some buttons ('OK', 'Cancel', 'Login', etc.,) in a `div` on modal which I pass dynamically as a JS object. Name of the button being the key and the callback function being the value.

**Examples:**

```
{
    "Login": function(){....}
}

{
    "OK": function(){...},
    "Cancel": function(){...}
}
```

Now I pass this kind of objects to a method `showPopup(message, buttonMap)` in the controller of the popup modal I have in view.

`message` being the display message on the popup and `buttonMap` being the object in examples.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('core').controller('PopupController', ['$rootScope', 'LogService', 'MessageHandlerService',
    function ($rootScope, LogService, MessageHandlerService) {    
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.buttonMap = {};
        ctrl.btnWidth = 100;

        $rootScope.$on('popup', showPopup);

        function showPopup (event, message, buttonMap) {
            $('#genericModalDialog .popup-content p').html(message);
            ctrl.buttonMap = buttonMap;
            var numberOfButtons = Object.keys(buttonMap).length;
            ctrl.btnWidth = (100 - numberOfButtons*2)/numberOfButtons;
            $("#genericModalDialog").modal('show');
        }

        ctrl.callbackFor = function callbackFor(key) {
            ctrl.buttonMap[key].call(null);
        };
    }
]);
```

**Service:**

```
    angular.module('core').service('PopupService', ['$rootScope', 'LogService', 'CacheService', 'MessageHandlerService',
        function ($rootScope, LogService) {

            this.isPopupShown = function (){
                return $("#genericModalDialog").hasClass('in');
            }

            this.showPopup = function (message, btnMap){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('popup', message, btnMap);
            }

            this.closePopup = function (){
                $("#genericModalDialog").modal('hide');
            }

        }
    ]);
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="PopupController as popupCtrl" class="modal fade" id="genericModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center" style="width:94%;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <br/><br/>
          <div class="popup-content">
            <p align="center"></p><br/>
            <div class="popup-action">
              <button type="button" class="btn" style="width:{{popupCtrl.btnWidth}}%; margin:1%" ng-repeat="(buttonName, callBack) in popupCtrl.buttonMap" ng-click="popupCtrl.callbackFor(buttonName)">{{buttonName}}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I don't want to instantiate `PopupController` in every other controller/service, I've written a service called `PopupService` which has a method that can called and will `$broadcast` an event called `"popup"` on `$rootscope` and I am handling this event in `PopupController`. Everything is triggered and working properly in this case. The only problem I face is the delay in rendering the popup on the UI, I see the message as soon as the popup is displayed but the rendering of buttons is very slow (approx 3 secs) this is because of loading of some other web page in the background.

When I searched about the issue on the internet I also found this total setup can be changed to a directive and the rendering of dynamic content (in this case the popup and buttons on it.) could be placed in a link function of the directive.

Another approach I saw was directly handling the DOM manipulation in the service which of course is not a good way.

Did I miss any other approach or a solution to this issue?

All I want to know is what would the best way be, to handling this situation which is programmatically and design wise good.

If I am not clear please let me know. I'll try explaining the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Directive would be a much better choice that the DOM manipulation. Additionally you should consider changing the usage of jQuery dialog into a https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6CKoEzN7EJ3rsLXcuDZ?p=preview) is an example how it can be done:

1) Create the directive

```
 app.directive('myModal', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       items: "=",
       message: "="
     },
     replace: true,
     templateUrl: "directiveTemplate.html",
     controller: function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

       $scope.open = function(size) {

         var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
           animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
           templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
           controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
           size: size,
           resolve: {
             items: function() {
               return $scope.items;
             },
             message: function() {
               return $scope.message;
             }
           }
         });

         modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
           $scope.button = selectedItem.name;
           $scope[selectedItem.callback](selectedItem.name);
         });
       };

     }
   }
 });
```

2) Create modalInstance directive

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, message) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.message = message;

  $scope.close = function(item) {
    $uibModalInstance.close(item);
  };
});
```

3) create directive template `directiveTemplate.html`

```
<div>
  {{buttonClicked}}
  <br> {{button}}

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">{{message}}</button>
</div>
```

4) create popup template 'myModalContent.html'

```
{{message}}
<button ng-repeat="item in items" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
```

5) define you controller where you will have list of buttons and message to be displayed in the popup (for demo purpose here are two different list of items and two messages)

```
 app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.message = "modal 1";
   $scope.items = [{
     name: 'item1',
     callback: "test1"
   }, {
     name: 'item2',
     callback: "test2"
   }, {
     name: 'item3',
     callback: "test3"
   }];

   $scope.message2 = "modal 12222";
   $scope.items2 = [{
     name: 'item1222',
     callback: "test1"
   }, {
     name: 'item2222',
     callback: "test2"
   }, {
     name: 'item3222',
     callback: "test3"
   }];

   $scope.test1 = function(message) {
     $scope.buttonClicked = "clicked test1";
   }
   $scope.test2 = function(message) {
     $scope.buttonClicked = "clicked test2";
   }
   $scope.test3 = function(message) {
     $scope.buttonClicked = "clicked test3";
   }

 });
```

and in order to you the directive you need:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <my-modal items="items" message="message"></my-modal>
    </br>
  <my-modal items="items2" message="message2"></my-modal>
</div>
```

If you have directive accessed from different angular application instances, than just inject directive application into the needed one (make sure the directive and modal instance to have a their own defined module ex: `var app = angular.module('myPopupDynamicModule', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);` and this is the one to be used for injection into other modules following this example: `var app2 = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'myPopupDynamicModule']);`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have some concerns here, even if I change the Jquery dialog to angular modal I should be able to trigger the popup display from a service whereas the DOM manipulation or dynamic content should be made available in the controller. This brings us to square 1 again, how can I trigger a method in Controller from a Service?

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi for this, you would just create the modalInstance in the controller and pass it to the service ahere will just open the modal. However I don't see why you mix the service (which should be separate from the view manipulation) with modal (which is a view component and should be maintained by controller or directive).I think you missunderstand the usage of the directive.

Comment: I am not mixing the service with UI. I want to change the content on the popup dynamically. both the message displayed and the buttons on the popup.

Comment: consider a situation where I want to display a popup, that could be from any other service or a controller. The only way I find easy is to use a service, which I can inject to any controller/service.

Comment: This should be a directive not a service. Directives are meant to help reusing the same component accross many places with dynamic content.

Comment: Okay, I am little new to angular, if possible, can you give me a reference where to look for to get an understanding on directives, I meant examples or a blog which explains the usage of directives. I am already going through the Angular docs.

Comment: I've created a demo directive for you. Will update my answer shortly.